# SQL Server Restore BACPAC throws error on a missing User-defined table type

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms, bacpac

I've exported an Azure SQL Database using the Azure Portal into a .bacpac file.

Using SQL Server Management Studio 17.9.1, I run the "import data-tier application" wizard and select the .bacpac file. It won't import successfully:

[image: Summary of failed actions]

One error message states:

[image]

So it looks like he is complaining that the "IntegerIdList" User-defined Table Type is not present (or he can't find it). But it is available in the source database:

[image]

Is there a way to import this bacpac file into an existing database? That way I can create this Table Type before I run this wizard.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no way to restore a bacpac to an existing database.

Try to install the latest version of SQL Server Management Studio (18.1 at this moment) and try again.

If the latest version of SSMS does not solve the issue, as a workaround copy the database with another name, script the user-defined table types (UDTT) and all dependent stored procedures, remove them from the newly created database and export this database instead of the original database. Restore the bacpac on your existing SQL Server and when the restore has finished, run the script that will create the UDTT and all dependent stored procedures.

UDTTs are supported on SQL Server 2008 and later only.